# Visual Studio Code: No tests discovered, please check the configuration settings for the test

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio

I am using visual studio code and want to run some test. I was using PC where it was working perfectly. I changed my system and copied all the files in same directory as these were before in old pc. But now visual studio does not recognizes the tests and this message keeps appearing up.
In settins.json under Workspace Settings I have,

```
{
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
"python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should check your start directory and your matching pattern (-s and -p options).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery

This configuration fixed it for me.

```
"python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": true,
"python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": false,
"python.unitTest.nosetestsEnabled": false,
"python.unitTest.unittestArgs": [
    "-v",
    "-s",
    "your_tests_directory",
    "-p",
    "test_*.py"
 ]
```

You can also play with the command line if you prefer it that way before setting the vs code configuration.

```
python -m unittest discover -v -s your_tests_directory -p test_*.py
```